# Video tag full screen issue with Flash file shown within object tag

Tags: html, css

In an application I am using video tag to show video file and object tag to show flash file(.swf). But after doing full screen any video, the flash file is showing on the video screen. Is there any way to hide the flash file when the video will be full screened?

[Flash file is showing on the video screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiyrY.jpg)

Comment: Please share you code with us in order we to help you

Comment: Seems like a `z-index` issue, can you provide your code or live demo?

Comment: It is only showing in Mozilla firefox browser but there is no problem in Chrome. object tag: <object style="width:100%" height="300" data="'.$flash_url.'"></object>. video tag: <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" style="width:99%" height="420" poster="<?php echo $poster_url; ?>" data-setup="{}">
      <source src="<?php echo $media_url; ?>" type='video/mp4' />
     </video>

Comment: Who can you ask a question without showing the code? Are we supposed to guess how your code looks like? As Alex wrote, show us your code! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It was just Firefox Nighty problem. Other browsers do not show any problem. Thanks everyone for co-operation.